# java gregoriancalendar off by an hour

Tags: java

I did:

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.French);
```

And the hour is off by one hour. I get 14:17 instead of 15:17.
My first thought was DST, but I think gregoriancalendar takes that into account.

The time is set correctly on my pc.

Comment: My bad, I forgot I had to use the TimeZone instead of Locale.

Comment: Actually, you want to use TimeZone *and* Locale. Otherwise your app might break horribly if it is ever instlled on a system with a default locale different from yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor you use is creating a Calendar with the default Timezone ([javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28java.util.Locale%29)), this might not be the timezone correct fpr the given locale. At leasst, thats how i read the javadoc. Try using a different constructor and pass your TZ in.

Comment: I confirm: "At leasst, thats how i read the javadoc."  -- thats how i read the source code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

As noted in a comment, you confused using a `Locale` object with specifying a time zone. A locale has *nothing* to do with a time zone, and a locale does *not* affect the meaning of the date-time value. A **locale affects only the formatting** of a String used in presentation of the date-time value.

No locale needed when capturing the current moment. But we do need a time zone.

```
Instant.now().atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
```

…or shorter version…

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Work in UTC

Much of your business logic, data storage, and data exchange should be in UTC. Think of UTC as “the One True Time”.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

## Specify time zone

As you figured out, you should always specify the desired/expected time zone. For any given moment, the date and the time-of-day vary around the world by zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

## Specify locale

Be aware that time zone and locale are orthogonal, completely separate issues.

- Time zone determines the meaning of the date-time, how we view its [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).
- Locale determines (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such.

This means we can mix-and-match any time zone with any locale. We can have a date-time in zone `Europe/Paris` with a locale of `Locale.KOREA`. Or a zone of `Pacific/Auckland` with `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`.

So locale only impact presentation of the date-time, how we generate a String representation of the date-time.

You can specify a custom formatting pattern for generation of strings. But better to let java.time automatically localize.

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                                       .withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying, but `GregorianCalendar(Locale)` is always based on your default time zone.  -- Mayb`e you should have a look at` GregorianCalendar(TimeZone zone, Locale aLocale)

Comment: As I said in my first comment I did indeed switch those 2.